# embed video is always autoplaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I don't understand why my embedded is always auto playing.

```
<div id="body15">
    <video width="480" height="270" controls>
        <source src="videos/ryan1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        <source src="videos/ryan1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="videos/ryan1.webm" type="video/webm">
        <object data="videos/ryan1.mp4" width="480" height="270">
            <embed width="600" height="270" src="movie.swf">
        </object>
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you add autoplay=""?

Comment: Try also with play="false"

Comment: Tried both of those options and nothing happens still auto playing

Comment: `autoplay` both `autoplay="true" ... autoplay="autoplay"` etc are same. Which browser autoplaying, all? If only `video` is autoplaying (not swf) temp. solution: `onReady( function(){ video.stop() --or-- video.pause() } )`

Comment: just safari is auto playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried controls="controls"?

```
<video width="480" height="270" controls="controls">
    <source src="videos/ryan1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="videos/ryan1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="videos/ryan1.webm" type="video/webm">
    <object data="videos/ryan1.mp4" width="480" height="270">
        <embed width="600" height="270" src="movie.swf">
    </object>
</video>
```

Comment: Yea I did it's still auto playing man I'm going mental over this

Comment: try adding autobuffer <video autobuffer width="480" height="270" controls="controls">

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is removing the <object><embed></object> code section?

Comment: @gVidal did you try removing the <object> and <embed> tags?  Did it help?